# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) - Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I was working on a project of an application to find the probability of winning in a game of Texas Hold'em.

My program has 3 data types given below.

```
typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
  CLUBS,
  NUM_SUITS
} suit_t;

struct card_tag {
  unsigned value;
  suit_t suit;
};

typedef struct card_tag card_t;

struct deck_tag {
      card_t ** cards;
        size_t n_cards;
};
typedef struct deck_tag deck_t;
```

I wrote a function `void shuffle(deck_t * d)` which is causing a segmentation fault:

```
void shuffle(deck_t * d){
    for (size_t i = d->n_cards-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        size_t randNum = random() % n_cards;
        card_t *temp = (d->cards+i);
        (d->cards+i) = (d->cards+randNum);
        (d->cards+randNum) = temp;      
    }
}
```

My program is being compiled. But while testing, at the point when the cards were shuffling, it said:

```sh
Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)
```

Comment: What range of numbers does random produce?  Please show the code on how are you allocating  the space for cards.

Comment: You have a core dump.  You should probably analyze it.

Comment: I tried analysing it, but I can't figure out what's going wrogn.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because the variable `randNum` may be bigger than `n_cards - 1` which means it tries to read memory that doesn't belongs to the program (to be more exact, memory that doesn't belongs to `d->cards`). So what you need to do is to ensure that:

```c
randNum < n_cards-1
```

One way to do this is by:

```c
size_t randNum = random() % (n_cards);
```

That way, the statment `randNum < n_cards-1` will always be `true`.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mitsake. I had written randNum=random()%n_cards; only. But the segmentation fault still exists.

Comment: @NityaPatel Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect your problem is in code you have not shown (specifically the allocation for `cards`. Suggest `card_t cards[4][13];` since the number of cards are fixed -- no need to dynamically allocate, or at least `card_t (*cards)[13];` so you get single allocation/free.